# How to center a container/item in a complex grid with material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-fog-yvvjp

I am trying to get the Avatar and Typography component below it to be perfectly in the center of the left section of the Paper component. After inspecting it with DevTools, it seems that the item/container component that Avatar and Typography are hosted in are not fully taking up their parent containers space. I have tried setting its height to 100%. I have also tried setting flexGrow to 1 as well. How would I accomplish a vertical and horizontal centering for the Avatar Typography component?

[image: Comp]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Container,
  Typography,
  Paper,
  makeStyles,
  Avatar,
  Grid
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    height: "15vh"
  },
  avatarSection: {
    height: '100%'
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container direction="row">
          <Grid
            item
            container
            direction="column"
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center"
            className={classes.avatarSection}
            xs={3}
          >
            <Avatar />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">Benjamin world</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={9}>
            <Typography variant="body1">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
              quam lorem, malesuada sed sapien non.
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your desire outcome ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have some extra classes which are not necessary.

[image: Screenshot]

You can achieve the vertical alignment with the codes below:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    height: "15vh"
  },
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container>
      <Paper>
        <Grid className={classes.paper} container alignItems="center" direction="row">
          <Grid
            item
            container
            direction="column"
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center"
            xs={3}
          >
            <Avatar />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">Benjamin world</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={9}>
            <Typography variant="body1">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
              quam lorem, malesuada sed sapien non.
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your outer Grid component, give it a css class with `height:'inherit'` Also add the prop `alignItems="center"`

Answer (score 0):

try this
    paper: {
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center'
    }

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the height of the grid container to 100%.

```
        <Grid style={{ height: "100%" }} container direction="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Container](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-container/) component, centers the content horizontally automatically. Notice the [CssBaseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/) component which helps to kickstart an consistent, and simple baseline to build upon.

To determine the maxWidth of the container you can use one of the [Breakpoints](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/): `'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl'`

```
import { Grid, Box, Container, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';

const Foo = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth='sm'>
        <Grid item>
          <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>green</Box>
          <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>grey</Box>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item>
          <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>orange</Box>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Foo;
```